# Unpack tuple into another tuple

Tags: f#, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Suppose I need to construct a tuple of length three:

```
(x , y, z)
```

And I have a function which returns a tuple of length two - `exampleFunction` and the last two elements of the tuple to be constructed are from this tuple.

How can I do this without having to call the `exampleFunction` two times:

```
(x, fst exampleFunction , snd exampleFunction)
```

I just want to do / achieve something like

```
(x, exampleFunction)
```

but it complains that the tuples have unmatched length ( of course )

Not looking at doing `let y,z = exampleFunction()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a built in function, but a custom one would work just as well.

```
let repack (a,(b,c)) = (a,b,c)
repack (x,exampleFunction)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it if worth a separate answer, but both answers provided above are not optimal since both construct redundant `Tuple<'a, Tuple<'b, 'c>>` upon invocation of the helper function. I would say a custom operator would be better for both readability and performance:

```
let inline ( +@ ) a (b,c) = a, b, c
let result = x +@ yz // result is ('x, 'y, 'z)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the function return `a*b` so the return type becomes `'a*('b*'c)` which is different to `'a*'b*'c` the best solution is a small helper function like

```
let inline flatten (a,(b,c)) = a,b,c
```

then you can do

```
(x,examplefunction) |> flatten
```

Comment: Yeah understand the why, looking for a way to do this. Pretty simple, still learning :)

Comment: @manojlds - you may be better off using record types for this sort of problem

Answer (score 0):

I have the following function in my common extension file.
You may find this useful.

```
   let inline squash12 ((a,(b,c)  ):('a*('b*'c)   )):('a*'b*'c   ) = (a,b,c  )
   let inline squash21 (((a,b),c  ):(('a*'b)*'c   )):('a*'b*'c   ) = (a,b,c  )
   let inline squash13 ((a,(b,c,d)):('a*('b*'c*'d))):('a*'b*'c*'d) = (a,b,c,d)

   let seqsquash12 (sa:seq<'a*('b*'c)   >) = sa |> Seq.map squash12
   let seqsquash21 (sa:seq<('a*'b)*'c   >) = sa |> Seq.map squash21
   let seqsquash13 (sa:seq<'a*('b*'c*'d)>) = sa |> Seq.map squash13

   let arrsquash12 (sa:('a*('b*'c)   ) array) = sa |> Array.map squash12
   let arrsquash21 (sa:(('a*'b)*'c   ) array) = sa |> Array.map squash21
   let arrsquash13 (sa:('a*('b*'c*'d)) array) = sa |> Array.map squash13
```